# Need to convert list<WebElement> into String array for string comparison

Tags: java, string, selenium, arraylist, selenium-webdriver

Target : I want to compare list of country code corresponding country name which is in Excel. Excel sheet have country code and country name in each column separated by ","(comma). I have taken this through below code.

```
String codes= hashmap.get("Country code"+i);
String countryname=hashmap.get("Country Name"+i);
String[] eachCNCODE= codes.split(",");
String[] eachCountry=countryname.split(",");
```

eachCNCODE & eachCountry arrays has the content of expected. Now i want to compare this with the content in webpage. so i have take webpage elements for countrycode & country name as below using List.

```
List<WebElement> countrycodes=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='TBL_QryRslts']/tbody/tr/td[4")
List<WebElement> countryNames=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='TBL_QryRslts']/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/a")
```

Now I want to compare eachCNCODE with countrycodes. Want to convert `List<WebElement>` into String array then I want to compare each . Please help me on this

Comment: You haven't posted any code where you tried to answer your own question... converting `List<WebElement>` to `String` array. Where is that code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
List<WebElement> countrycodes=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='TBL_QryRslts']/tbody/tr/td[4")
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
for(WebElement e : countrycodes){
    strings.add(e.getText());
}
```

Hope it will help you.